# Не могу запустить websocket server в веб приложении

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

Здравствуйте. Не могу разобраться в ситуации - создаю websocket сервер, деплою на tomcat, пытаюсь подключится клиентом, но ничего не получается. Что-то мне подсказывает, что websocket класс нужно еще каким-то образом "зарегистрировать", чтобы мое приложение его видело, но я нигде не нашел примера. 

Беру самый простой пример (дабы не копипастить сюда код, кину ссылку) http://dreamand.me/java/jee7-websocket-example/ 

 Использую: Idea, tomcat 7

Иерархия моего проекта следующая:

```
-src
 -main
  -java
   -websocket
     ChatServer.java
  -webapp
   -files
     index.html
   -WEB-INF
     web.xml
```

Comment: Проверьте адреса приложения, вебсокета. Если вы назвали свой прожект иначе, чем  `websocket`, то пример работать не будет. `var chatClient = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/websocket/chat");` должно соответствовать названию приложения. Если `myApp`, то `var chatClient = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/myApp/chat");`

Comment: По этому пути у меня находится класс с сокетом: WEBSocketServer\src\main\java\websocket\ChatServer.java Класс имеет аннотацию @ServerEndpoint(value = "/chat"). Я пишу так: var chatClient = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/WEBSocketServer/chat"); - не работает, так  new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/WEBSocketServer/websocket/chat"); тоже не работает

Comment: index.html по какому адресу открывается в браузере? `http://localhost:8080/WEBSocketServer/index.html`

Comment: http://localhost:8080/files/index.html по этому адресу. В первом посте приведена иерархия, этот файл находится по пути webapp-files-index.html

Comment: Странно. Но раз так, тогда `var chatClient = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/chat");`

Comment: тоже самое, не работает :(

Comment: Собрал проект, как описано по указанной ссылке, развернул на Tomcat 7 (хотя написано про GlassFish 4), всё работает. То же самое на Wildfly 10. Смотрите, что у вас на сервере лежит, возможно, что собрали неправильно. Плюс Tomcat может распаковывать .war-файлы в папку: возможно в такой папке лежит какая-нибудь нерабочая версия, а новые war-файлы игнорируются. В общем пример рабочий, смотрите у себя что не так. Насчёт вашего "Использую: Idea, tomcat 7" - использовать можно по разному, в вопросе не указано что и как разворачивается на сервере

Comment: @PREDATORik вот работающий сервер с примерами http://java-websocket.org/